# Mat Sort Issue for Numbers and Text Columns

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5, angular-cdk

I have angular material datasource. angular material version is ^5.0.3 Sorting is working. However for some columns it is sorting incorrectly. where number and text is there. For instance, sorted result like, 'XXX', '1', '1tesxt', '1', 'OPD', OXD', '12'.

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort > 
  <ng-container matColumnDef="model">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Model </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.model}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8):

This is because the standard `sortingDataAccessor` casts number strings to number and in Javascript `1 > 'one'` and `1 < 'one'` both evaluates to `false`.

As a workaround, you can define your own `sortingDataAccessor` without the cast:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {    
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, attribute) => data[attribute];
}
```

The workaround is copied from this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9966#issuecomment-365942460).

Answer (score 1):

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => ['length', 'age'].includes(property) ? +item[property] : item[property];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out those characters that are not numbers and convert the string that is holding the numeric characters to a numeric type value.

Your initial column value: 'ID0239'.
After taking out the characters: '0239'.
After converting the string to number: 0239.

And 0239 is the value you need to return inside the sortingDataAccessor function.